# ajax text variable passing 0 or NaN

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, nan

I'm trying to pass the  variable **var_nome**  to a php file using the code bellow. 
The value of this var is coming from a text field in a html form. If the value of the field is a number, it works perfectly and I get the data on teh php page **BUT** if the value of **var_nome** is a text, I got 'NaN' as a result?

```js
function AlteraNomePortfolioAjax(portfolios_id, var_nome, SuccessDiv) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    url: 'PRT_ope_ajax.php',
    data: {
      'portfolios_id': +portfolios_id,
      'var_nome': +var_nome
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $(SuccessDiv).html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove that `+` sign, it is attempting to convert the variables to an integer:

```
data: {'portfolios_id' : portfolios_id , 'var_nome' : var_nome  },
```

Comment: Thank you.. Works perfectly

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, mark it as such by clicking the tick under the voting buttons.

Comment: *"to an integer"* - `NaN` isn't an integer, nor is the result of, say, `+"1.5"`. (Though obviously you are correct that those unary plus operators were the problem.)

Comment: "attempting to" then, I shall edited the post accordingly ;)